# p:selectOneMenu value not set in bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

In **p:selectOneMenu** loginbranchName value is not set in bean.In selectItems having list of branchName.I'm using listener to select value from list but value not set in getLoginBranchId method....

```
<h:outputLabel value="Branch Name:*" style="text-align: left;display: block;" rendered="#{loginBean.userLoggedIn}"/>
                <p:selectOneMenu value="#{loginBean.loginbranchName}"
                    rendered="#{loginBean.userLoggedIn}"
                    style="width:175px;">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select" itemValue="0" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{loginBean.branchName}" />
                    <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{loginBean.getLoginBranchId}"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
```

**login.java**

```
public String getLoginbranchName() {
    return loginbranchName;
}

public void setLoginbranchName(String loginbranchName) {
    System.out.println("loginbranchName"+loginbranchName);
    this.loginbranchName = loginbranchName;
}
public void getLoginBranchId()
{
    System.out.println("enter into getloginbranchid");
    System.out.println("loginbranchName"+loginbranchName);
    int unitId=loginDAO.getLoginBranchId(loginbranchName);
    System.out.println("unitId"+unitId);
}
```

Comment: What's the scope of your bean?

Comment: Don't use `get` notation for your POST behaviour methods. `get` notation ones are supposed to return a value.

Comment: I'm using @SessionScoped

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@BalusC was correct regarding the above discussion where, JSF2 can work with **List** and **SelectItem** https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info I think you might be missing

```
<h:form> 
</h:form>
```

tag.

Comment: @BalusC I think this would be the problem, what do you think?

Comment: Good to know that @Angelina